# How to send String using HttpURLConnection in android

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection

I need to send a String to my Web Service and I have doubts about how to send string using HttpURLConnection.

Obs: in String "result" I have something like:

```
 {"sex":"Famale","nome":"Larissa Aparecida Nogueira","convenios":[{"convenio":2,"tipo":"Principal","number":"44551-1456-6678-3344"}],"user":"lari.ap","email":"lari.ap@yahoo.com.br","cell":"(19)98167-5569"}
```

following is my code:

```
   public UsuerService(Context context, String result) {
       this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
       this.context = context;
       this.result = result;
   }

  @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String responseString = "";
        try {
             URL url = new URL(Constants.USUARIO + "/createUsuario");
             HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");


             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
             String inputLine;
             StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

             while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
             response.append(inputLine);
           }

            result = response.toString();
            bufferedReader.close();
           } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getMessage());
        }

         return null;
   }
```

I have a Class that picks up my data and parses it to JsonObject.
I need to understand how to send my object.toString() for web service using HttpURLConnection.

following is the code:

```
 public String parserUsuarioJson(){

    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

    try {
        object.put(Constants.KEY_NAME, mUsuario.getNome());
        object.put(Constants.KEY_EMAIL, mUsuario.getEmail());
        object.put(Constants.KEY_USER, mUsuario.getUser());
        object.put(Constants.KEY_PASS, mUsuario.getSenha());
        object.put(Constants.KEY_SEX, mUsuario.getSexo());
        object.put(Constants.KEY_CELLPHONE, mUsuario.getCelular());

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < mUsuario.getUsuarioConvenios().size() ; i++){
            JSONObject convenio = new JSONObject();

            convenio.put(Constants.KEY_CONVENIO, mUsuario.getUsuarioConvenios().get(i).getConvenio().getId());
            convenio.put(Constants.KEY_NUMBER, mUsuario.getUsuarioConvenios().get(i).getNumero());
            convenio.put(Constants.KEY_TYPE, mUsuario.getUsuarioConvenios().get(i).getTipo());

            array.put(convenio);
        }
        object.put(Constants.KEY_CONVENIOS, array);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("Register", e.getMessage());
    }

    return object.toString();

}
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Use volley for all NetworkCalls in android. Its Google library and very easy to use. http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: You should pseudonymize the information, as you've just posted some womans cell phone number on the internet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **NameValuePairList** to send the data.

Try something like this...

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.USUARIO + "/createUsuario");

try { 
        // Add your key-value pair here
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sex", "female"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nome", "Larissa Aparecida Nogueira"));
        // set all other key-value pairs

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    }
```

For Sending json Object over network using http post.

pass the json string here

```
 StringEntity se = new StringEntity(object.toString());
 httpost.setEntity(se);
 httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
 httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
```

Don't forget to catch the exception.

Sending json Object using httpurlConnection...

```
try {
  //constants
  URL url = new URL(Constants.USUARIO + "/createUsuario");
  String yourJsonString = object.toString();

  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
  conn.setDoInput(true);
  conn.setDoOutput(true);
  conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(yourJsonString.getBytes().length);

  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
  conn.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

  conn.connect();

  OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
  os.write(yourJsonString.getBytes());

  os.flush();

  InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
} finally {  
  //clean up
  os.close();
  is.close();
  conn.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Hello Ritesh. Thank you for you response, but I have an class that parser my data to Json Object. I update my question with this class. I need understand how to I send object.toString() for my web service using httpurlconnection. thanks

Comment: HttpClient or HttpURLConnection?? I cannot find HttpClient

Comment: thats because HttpClient api is not in your project. Have tried using HttpURLConnection?

Comment: yes. I'm using HttpURLConnection but I think that HTTPURLConnection not use StringEntitiy se = new StringEntity(object.toString());

Comment: how to use httpost.setEntity(se); in HttpUrlConnection? do you know?

Comment: I put answer in this question, can you please check if its correct? thanks. and sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

As I am getting ,You want to send a String to a Webservice . I am giving you a sample code here ,where I am sending some string values to a webservice . It's working code `

```
    private class BackgroundOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
            //Your network connection code should be here .
            String response = postCall("Put your WebService url here");
            return response ;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //Print your response here .
            Log.d("Post Response",result);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }

        public static String postCall(String uri) {
        String result ="";
        try {
            //Connect
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(uri).openConnection()));
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.connect();
            //Write
            OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
//Call parserUsuarioJson() inside write(),Make sure it is returning proper json string .
            writer.write(parserUsuarioJson());
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            //Read
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String line = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Now you can call above from from your activity's onCreate() function using below code .

```
new BackgroundOperation().execute("");
```

Note : Don't forget to mention below permission in your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Note : Make sure

1 . parserUsuarioJson() is returning proper json string .

2 . Your webservice is working .

Comment: Hello Android Dev. Thank you for you response, but I have an class that parser my data to Json Object. I update my question with this class.

Comment: I need understant how to I send object.toString(); for my web service using httpURLConnection. thanks :)

Comment: I have edited the answer to meet your requirement . It will work definitely if your parserUsuario() is returning proper json and your webservice is working .

Comment: Response from Webservice will be printed in LogCat . So check your Logcat after executing new BackgroundOperation().execute("");

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {

        URL url = new URL(Constants.USUARIO + "/createUsuario");
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(result.getBytes().length);

        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

        httpURLConnection.connect();

        OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
        os.write(result.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

        os.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: what is "result"? It has been used twice